# How would you add a crsf token inside the html

Tags: python, django

```
form="<form action='addAppointment/' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'><button type='submit'>Book now</button></form>"
```

I am currently adding the form element to a page through html the goal of this is to book an appointment.

How would I go about adding the crsf_token into the string.

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Traceback

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

Got it to work like so

```
token = django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)
print("token: ",token)
form='<form action="/addAppointment/'+self.username+"/"+time+ '/"'+ ' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><button type="submit">Book now</button>'+'<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"'+'value="'+token+'"'+ 'type="hidden">'+'</form>'
```

Answer (score 5):

In form `{% csrf_token %}` has to be inside the form. The best just after opening it.

```
<form method="post" ...>
    {% csrf_token %}
    # rest of the form
</form>
```

Comment: ... and the rest of the form doesn't actually have to be nested within `<form>...</form>` if you use `<form id="form_id">` and attach its other elements with form=, for example `<input form="form_id" ...> `

Comment: I am creating multiple form buttons. So this won't work.